# missing lifetime specifier [E0106] on function signature

Tags: rust

I'm pretty confused by the errors from this simple code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e517d7dca727ce27d30d50391f020095&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn main() {
    let a = fn1("test123");
}

fn fn1(a1: &str) -> &str {
    let a = fn2();
    a
}

fn fn2() -> &str {
    "12345abc"
}
```

These are:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> <anon>:10:13
   |
10 | fn fn2() -> &str {
   |             ^ expected lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
   = help: consider giving it a 'static lifetime
```

I haven't been faced with these errors before, has anything changed in a recent Rust version? How can I fix the errors?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A long time ago, when a function returned a borrowed pointer, the compiler inferred the `'static` lifetime, so `fn2` would compile successfully. Since then, lifetime elision has been implemented. Lifetime elision is a process where the compiler will automatically link the lifetime of an input parameter to the lifetime of the output value without having to explicitly name it.

For example, `fn1`, without lifetime elision, would be written like this:

```rust
fn fn1<'a>(a1: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    let a = fn2();
    a
}
```

However, `fn2` has no parameters that are borrowed pointers or structs with lifetime parameters (indeed, it has no parameters at all). You must therefore mention the lifetime explicitly. Since you're returning a string literal, the correct lifetime is `'static` (as suggested by the compiler).

```rust
fn fn2() -> &'static str {
    "12345abc"
}
```