# missing lifetime specifier [E0106] on type alias

Tags: rust, lifetime, type-alias

This code:

```
use std::fmt;
use std::result::Result::{self, Ok, Err};

#[derive(Clone)]
#[derive(Copy)]
enum Tile {
    White,
    Black,
    Empty
}
type Board = &[[Tile; 19]; 19];
```

Produces this error:

```
Compiling go v0.1.0 (file:///home/max/gits/go_rusty)
src/main.rs:12:14: 12:31 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
src/main.rs:12 type Board = &[[Tile; 19]; 19];
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `go`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I'm having a hard time finding anything that explains what a lifetime specifier is and why I would need that on a type alias declaration.

Comment: uhm... you're right about the `finding anything that explains...`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0106 doesn't exist yet, the book doesn't contain the word "specifier" in the [lifetime-chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/lifetimes.html)... related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097710/error-missing-lifetime-specifier-e0106

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is

```
type Board<'a> = &'a [[Tile; 19]; 19];
```

---

Rust is always explicit about generic arguments. Lifetimes also are generic arguments. Imagine you'd be generic over the `Tile` type.

```
type Board = &[[T; 19]; 19];
```

This would cause an error about `T` not existing (except if you defined an actual type named `T`). But you'd like to be able to use `Board` for any inner type. So what you'd need to do is to add a generic argument to the definition:

```
type Board<T> = &[[T; 19]; 19];
```

So whenever you use the `Board` type alias, you also need to pass the `T` type.

Back to our lifetime issue. Our type alias has a reference. We don't know what the lifetime of this reference is. The reason why you rarely need to specify a lifetime is [lifetime-elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision). This is one of the cases where you need to specify the lifetime, since you want the lifetime to be determined at all locations where you use `Board`, like as if you used `&[[Tile; 19]; 19]` everywhere directly. At the type alias definition the only available lifetime is `'static`, so we need to define a new generic one.

Comment: OK, so I think the core problem with my code is that I really wanted to define the value (not the reference), and then create references to that value later, which seems to have worked: `type Board = [[Tile; 19]; 19];` compiles correctly. I am then able to `let board:&Board = &[[Tile::Empty; 19]; 19];` later on.

Comment: However, I'm not sure I understand lifetimes, even after reading the documentation you linked to. It explains clearly the syntax for naming lifetimes of things in functions, but I don't understand what giving it a name does. For example, if I declare `type Board<'a> = &'a [[Tile; 19]; 19];` at the top level, where does `'a` end? Also, why doesn't the compiler give my original line `'static` by default?

Comment: Maybe https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-struct-definitions will help?